# threads in android no output

Tags: java, android

I've created an android app where the user inputs a string and a number, where the number will be calculated to its factorial. Everything's working fine but when i enclose my code inside the thread there's no output.

here's my source code:

```
package com.inputandfactorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button chkCmd;
    EditText input1, input2;
    TextView display1, display2;
    int res = 1,factint;
    String fact;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bProcess);
        input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etString);
        input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFactorial);
        display1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvString);
        display2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFactorial);

        chkCmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {



                Thread t1 = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        String change = input1.getText().toString();
                        fact = input2.getText().toString();
                        factint = Integer.parseInt(fact);
                        for (int i = 1; i <= factint; i++) {
                            res = res * i;
                        }
                        try {
                            display2.setText("The factorial of " + fact + " is " + res);
                            display1.setText("The string value is " + change);
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                };
                t1.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I know i don't need to put it in a thread, i just was just experiment to see if this will work and it didn't.

Comment: Don't make extra problems for yourself.  Unless you need threads, don't use them.

Comment: I just wanna learn stuff, I might encounter this problem in the future, this will save me time and frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only manipulate `View`s on the UI thread. Wrap your code in a `Runnable` and execute it on the main thread with `Activity#runOnUiThread(Runnable action)`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        display2.setText("The factorial of " + fact + " is " + res);
        display1.setText("The string value is " + change);
    }
}
```

That said, simple arithmetic doesn't warrant the use of a `Thread` in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

You can't make change on the UI from a Thread. All changes on the UI need to be done on the UIThread. To do that easily, use an AsyncTask :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: If you use an `AsyncTask`, you should manipulate the UI with the task's results in `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment above about you not needing threading however in the interest of answering your question...

You need to look at [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). I wrote a previous answer that should provide you with a working example [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example/9671602#9671602)

It goes on to explain you can only affect the UI from the original GUI thread therefore your code above will not work.

Comment: If you use an `AsyncTask`, you should manipulate the UI with the task's results in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Please see my link in my answer - it explains all of this in greater detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example/9671602#9671602

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Its always a good practice to keep the **UI work on the UI thread, and Non-UI work on the Non-UI thread**. That became a **law** with the release of `HoneyComb` Android Version.

**2.** An **android** application **starts on the UI thread**, creating any **other thread will drop you out of the Android thread**, and this thread will be the Non-UI thread.

**3.** To post the work **from** the `Non-UI` thread **back on** the `UI` thread, we need to use these **2 ways:**

**-** `Thread` along with `Handler`.

**-** `AsyncTask`, which is specially introduced in Android **to sync UI and Non-UI thread**, Its also known as `Painless threading`.